# Dynamically insert Enum symbols with Avro java api

Tags: java, api, schema, avro

I'm writing a schema for a java class that has an enum field. I'm using the java schema builder like this:

```
public Schema schema = SchemaBuilder
    .record("MyRecord").namespace("my.name.space")
    .name("myEnum").type().enumeration("MyEnumClass").namespace("enum.name.space")
        .symbols("S1", ..., "S1000").noDefault()
    .endRecord()
```

The problem is that there are hundreds of Enum values in MyEnumClass. The class is accessible from my code. How can I insert them dynamically into `.symbles()` without manually typing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create avro schema for your class automatically.

For example.

Enum:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    VAL1,
    VAL2,
    VAL3
}
```

Class with enum field:

```
public class TestClass {
    public TestEnum testEnum;

    public TestClass() {

    }

    public TestClass(TestEnum testEnum) {
        this.testEnum = testEnum;
    }

    public TestEnum getTestEnum() {
        return testEnum;
    }

    public void setTestEnum(TestEnum testEnum) {
        this.testEnum = testEnum;
    }
}
```

Generating schema:

```
Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(TestClass.class);
```

Result:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "TestClass",
  "namespace": "q42698247",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "testEnum",
      "type": {
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "TestEnum",
        "symbols": [
          "VAL1",
          "VAL2",
          "VAL3"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As DontPanic says in his response, you can use reflection to build directly from the enum type.  However, if you don't have a Java enum type to work with, there is another way.

The method in question, EnumBuilder.symbols(String... symbols) is using a 'vararg' String argument.  See this for details on varargs.  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs

In practice, Arrays can be converted to varargs parameters, as long as the types match.  So, you could do (code below isn't validated with a compiler, but you get the idea)

```
List<String> enumElements = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
  enumElements.add("S"+i);
};
String[] enumElementsArray = enumElements.toArray(new String[0]);

public Schema schema = SchemaBuilder
    .record("MyRecord").namespace("my.name.space")
    .name("myEnum").type().enumeration("MyEnumClass").namespace("enum.name.space")
        .symbols(enumElementsArray).noDefault()
    .endRecord();
```